# Proper notation for defining a repeating sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, notation

How would one go about properly defining a sequence that, say, repeats the integers $\{1, 2, 3, \dots, n\}$ infinitely many times? Seemed very simple at first, but currently grappling with the proper way to go about this. If anyone could offer some insight that would be much appreciated.

Edit: For clarity, I mean a sequence of the form $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots n, 1, 2, 3, \ldots n, 1, 2, 3, \ldots n, \ldots\}$

Comment: Do you mean a sequence of the sort $1,2,\ldots, n,1,2,\ldots, n,1,2,\ldots, n, \ldots$ ?

Comment: @oliverjones Yes, precisely.

Comment: $a_k = (k\% n)+1$ using $\%$ as the modulo operator.

Comment: Sometimes for sequences made up of concatenating patterns more complicated than this one together, the simplest description is not an "explicit" formula, but a description of the pattern generating the strings and then the instruction to concatenate them together. I realize that wasn't the question, but I just note that indirect descriptions than formulas can still be perfectly good ways of "properly" defining a sequence if they are unambiguous. Whether they help you solve problems is another question (but sometimes explicit formulas don't make that any easier either).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more general problems of this nature, employ not one rule, but more than one rule.  Then, each rule could have a specific range.  For example, for the present query:

Assume that $k \in \mathbb{Z^+}.$

Rule 1
For $k \leq n, a_k = k.$

Rule 2
For $k > n, a_k = a_{(k-n)}.$

Answer (score 1):

Set $a_1 = 1, a_2 = 1 +_n a_1 , a_{m+1} = 1+_n \,a_m$ where $+_n$ is addition modulo n on the set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. That is $1 +_n 1 =2, 2+_n 1 =3, \ldots n-1 +_n 1 = n, n+_n 1 = 1, \ldots$

Then $a_1 = 1, \ldots a_n = n, a_{n+1} = 1, \ldots a_{n+n} = n, a_{2n+1} = 1, \ldots$